# Google App Invites invitations not being sent

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

As of 11/11/2015 Google App Invites are no longer sending out emails. SMS still works. Has anyone else experienced this? My app code has not changed in the last few weeks so suspected might be something to do with Play Services 8.3 - but that doesn't seem to be the cause.

I have checked:

- No special characters in message
- Updated to latest Play Services 8.3
- Included `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'`

InvitiationIds are being generated and no errors are being thrown.

Any suggestions of what else might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2015-11-12 the email invites have started working again.
No code was changed in my app and the emails have started working.

However, Invites sent yesterday are still lost.

I can only put it down to a service issue with Google.

I guess that's why Google App Invites is still in beta.

I will mark this answer as "accepted" in a few hours... just in case anyone from Google is reading and wants to comment and confirm what the issue was.

Comment: for me its is not working..!  i am getting this message "message failed to send "

Comment: beanmonger, I was implement a Google Invite Activity, create realse SHA1, set all configurations in my class and publish app like a beta version. And the Google Invite Service doesn't works. Can it be because of the version app is beta, not realse ?

Answer (score 0):

There was an update, as explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/):

> App Invites is a technology that enables your users to share your app with people they know. If you build using App Invites, Google Play services 8.3 has an update that will make coding much simpler. Now, you can use the AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation() method. This will set up a ResultCallback that you can use to launch your deep link activity, drastically simplifying your code.

Comment: That relates to processing the App Invite once received. The issue I'm having is the sending of invites using the `AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder`